# How to match a regex pattern from a certain position in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the markdown header using regex in javascript. A markdown header is a string starting from one or more `#` followed by one or more spaces and some more texts, like this:

```markdown
## This is the title
```

The tricky thing is, I'm given a multi-line string and a 0-indexed start position, I need to check if the string starting from the given position **starts** with a markdown header. In other words, I need to write the following function:

```js
/**
 * The function should return true in the following situations:
 * - text: "abc\n# My Title", startPos = 4
 * - text: "abc\n# My Title\nxyz", startPos = 4
 * 
 * The function should return false in the following situation:
 * - text "abc\n#My Title", startPos = 0
 */
function isMarkdownHeader(text, startPos) {
    ...
}
```

Here is what I've tried:

```js
function isMarkdownHeader(text, startPos) {
    const pattern = new RegExp(`^[^]{${startPos}}(^#+)(\\s+)(.*$)`, 'm');
    return pattern.exec(text) != null;
}

console.log(isMarkdownHeader("abc\n## My Title\nxyz", 4)); // true
console.log(isMarkdownHeader("abc\n## My Title\nxyz", 0)); // true, which is incorrect.
```

The function should return `false` in the second invocation. But it didn't. Why? How can I make it work?

Comment: Well ``isMarkdownHeader("abc\n## My Title\nxyz", 0)`` returns true because there is one or more `#` chars at the start of a line. Why should it be false?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Maybe I didn't make it clear enough. I only want to check the line starting from `startPos`. Because `startPos` is `0` in this case, the line starting from `startPos` is `abc`, which doesn't contain `#` at all. I don't care about the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution using Regex

You can use

```
^.{4}(#+\s+.*)
```

And the function will look

```
function isMarkdownHeader(text, startPos) {
    const pattern = new RegExp(`^.{${startPos}}#+\\s+.*`, "s");
    return pattern.exec(text) != null;
}

isMarkdownHeader("abc\n## My Title\nxyz", 4)  // true
isMarkdownHeader("abc\n## My Title\nxyz", 0)  // false
```

NOTE: Here I have used `s` flag. Also, see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2w4DUH/1).

#### Solution using Slice

You can slice the input string before checking the validity.

```
function isMarkdownHeader(text, startPos) {
    const pattern = /^#+\s+.*/;
    return !!pattern.exec(text.slice(startPos));
}

isMarkdownHeader("abc\n## My Title\nxyz", 4)  // true
isMarkdownHeader("abc\n## My Title\nxyz", 0)  // false
```

##### *Edit*

> `isMarkdownHeader("abcd## My Title\nxyz", 4)` should return `false`. With your code, the return value is `true`

That occurs because the stuff called newline and the `\n` character is not the same thing. `\n` in a string is a regular character of the newline and it becomes a newline after we print the string. So if if you want to match both of them then use

```
^.{4}(?:^|\n|\\n)(#+\s+.*)
```

##### Here I added `(?:^|\n|\\n)` pattern to the old one

- `(?:` Non-capturing group

  - `^|\n|\\n` Match **start of a string** or **newline** or `\n` character
- `)` Close non-capturing group

##### It matches for

- [`abcd\n## My Title\nxyz`](https://regex101.com/r/a5skPc/1)
- [`abcd⏎## My Title\nxyz`](https://regex101.com/r/bBSquE/1) where `⏎` is a newline

##### And it does not match for

- [`abcd## My Title\nxyz`](https://regex101.com/r/3wHWq6/1)

P.S. For matching `abc\n## My Title\nxyz` you have to use `3` as a `startPos`, not including the `\n` character.

```
function isMarkdownHeader(text, startPos) {
    const pattern = new RegExp(`^.{${startPos}}(?:^|\\n|\\\\n)(#+\\s+.*)`, "s");
    return pattern.exec(text) != null;
}

console.log(isMarkdownHeader("abc\n## My Title\nxyz", 3))  // true
console.log(isMarkdownHeader("abc\n## My Title\nxyz", 0))  // false
console.log(isMarkdownHeader("abcd## My Title\nxyz", 4))  // false
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xNBVGW/1), the `{0}` quantifier causes the previous token to be ignored.  There's no citation to back that, but I'll take them at their word.

That being so, you can check that your match starts at index 0 (which indicates that the string started with the correct number of ignored characters).

```
function isMarkdownHeader(text, startPos) {
    const pattern = new RegExp(`^[^]{${startPos}}(^#+)(\\s+)(.*$)`, 'm');
    const match = pattern.exec(text);
    return match?.index === 0;
}

console.log(isMarkdownHeader("abc\n## My Title\nxyz", 4)); // true
console.log(isMarkdownHeader("abc\n## My Title\nxyz", 0)); // now false
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the regex to start at a certain position. You can just pass the substring starting at `startPos`:

```
return pattern.exec(text.substring(startPos)) != null;
```

Comment: The behavior of `text.substring()` doesn't seem to be documented. If it copies all the characters of `text` from `startPos`, the speed might be slow. I want a faster solution.